# Identity Server 4 with react

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, identityserver4

Is there anyone that could help me with this problem? The thing is, I created new dotnet app with

dotnet new react --auth Individual -o

like it is said in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Authentication works nicely, but the problem is, I want to change layout of the login/register page, replacing it with my own react page. However, I don't really see any method of doing this. I tried to POST directly to  /Identity/Account/Login, but it doesn't work since it uses __RequestVerificationToken on its form. I've also tried to simply create my own endpoint and use SignInManager in it, but I don't know how to actually get accessToken and send it back to frontend, I've searched for it, but didn't find anything helpful.

Does anyone know the answer? I'm beggining to think that it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Identity comes as razor class library in .net core but you can scaffold identity to include the code selectively in your project.
[Must give it a read before proceeding - Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

> In solution explorer => Right click on your project =>
> Add => New Scaffolded Item => select identity