# Adding Identity to Existing React Project

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-6.0

I have already created a React App and have built out a decent amount of it but I wanted to have identity like described in this post:
[Identity Server 4 with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550692/identity-server-4-with-react)

And in this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The issue is that I have already created my React app and I cannot simply just run the following command again:

```
dotnet new react -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual
```

as that would overwrite my current app. I was wondering if there were a way to add that -au Individual to an existing react app.

Thank you!!

Comment: My best advice is creating the new project with identity some where else, inspecting it and take the part that's needed to your project. I suggest also you use git versioning to ensure not losing your current work.

Comment: Remember also the old identity server is open source and free to use but is not maintained longer but the duende is the paid and maintained version